how can i trigger redux dispatch method in form action?
<form ref={formRef} action={() => dispatch(addIncome())}>


Type '() => { payload: undefined; type: "income/addIncome"; }' is not assignable to type '(formData: FormData) => void | Promise'.
Type '{ payload: undefined; type: "income/addIncome"; }' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(3209, 9): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes, HTMLFormElement>'

I get this error.how can i handle it ?

Please [edit] your post to explain (1) what you set out to achieve, (2) what code you wrote for that and why, ideally in [mcve] form, (3) what that code did that you didn't expect, and (4) what debugging and (re)searching. Right now your post doesn't have anything folks can answer: you don't say what you're doing, you don't show enough code to even explain where the error gets triggered, and you haven't talk about what you already tried before posting.

The form action prop is typed (formData: FormData) => void | Promise', e.g. a function that receives the form's formdata and returns nothing or a Promise object (i.e. an async function handler). You are using a function that accepts no formData argument and returns the dispatch result via an implicit arrow function return.
Update your usage to:

accept an argument
use a void return

Examples:
Typescript
<form
  ref={formRef}
  action={(_formData: FormData) => {
    dispatch(addIncome());
  }}
>
  ...
</form>

Javascript
<form
  ref={formRef}
  action={(_formData) => { // You might be able to omit arg in JS
    dispatch(addIncome());
  }}
>
  ...
</form>

Considering you don't appear to be using server actions and if all you need to do is dispatch an action when the form is submitted then perhaps the onSubmit handler is more appropriate.
Example:
<form
  ref={formRef}
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit form and reload page
    dispatch(addIncome());
  }}
>
  ...
</form>

